# Command to print users that don't have /sbin/nologin as a shell

Tags: command-line, etc

Given the /etc/passwd file, what is the command to print only the login names of users that do not have /sbin/nologin as a shell?

Also, in my /etc directory, what can I use as a command to count the # of files that start with the letter 's'? Kind of new to this, thank you!

Comment: In the future, please ask one question per question. Especially in view of the fact that in this case, your 2 questions are TOTALLY unrelated to one another. Also, they are both trivial.

Comment: And they look like homework questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print only users that have no login shell you can use awk only in it's simplest case:

```
awk -F/ '$NF != "nologin"' /etc/passwd
```

Here we use `-F/` as delimiter and then `'$NF =! "nologin"' where`$NF`is the last field of the line/row. The default action in`awk` is print so it'll print the whole line.

Finding all files starting with an `s` can easily be done using `find`. GnuFind in this case

```
find /etc/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 's*' -printf '%P\n'
```

Here we use GNU`find` to search for `/etc/` being the path then we check one level (no subdirectories).

`-type f` tells find to check files only.
`-name 's*` self explanatory 
`-printf '%P\n'`  The `'%P'` is a printf format. See `man find` for more.

Comment: awk is cool. But find for sample list for me is overkill

Comment: @RomeoNinov  `find` might be an overkill but it is very accurate in checking directories. Parsing `ls` output is in general not Recommended.

Comment: val0x00ff, using awk will be also quite sample: ls -l|awk '/^-/ {} END {print NR}'

Comment: @RomeoNinov Again, parsing ls output is not recommended. `ls -l` will also show the total bytes as the first field. Then the OP asks about files only and not folders,subfolders or files found in subfolders. Why you shouldn't parse `ls` output is explained here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

```
1. grep -v '/sbin/nologin' /etc/passwd|awk -F: '{print $1}'

2. ls s*|wc -w
```

Or better:

```
2. ls -l s*|wc -l
```

to avoid error when you have filename with space(s)

Comment: Actually there's no need to print out all the information with `-l` if you can simply use `ls -1 s* | wc -l`. Not that it matters much ;)

Comment: IMHO the result is the same (with l or 1) as wc command count the newline characters

Comment: It is, of course. I'm not saying there is anything wrong with your answer because there isn't. I'm just pointing it out because the `-1` switch is somewhat less known and may sometimes come handy.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
grep -v "/sbin/nologin$" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1
```

Second:

```
ls -ld /etc/s* | wc -l
```